# Code-Golf: Count Islands

Tags: code-golf

A simple contest, inspired by [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936073/can-counting-contiguous-regions-in-a-bitmap-be-solved-in-better-than-or-c/11936456):

> You are given an image of a surface photographed by a satellite.The image is a bitmap where water is marked by '`.`' and land is marked by '`*`'. Groups of adjacent '`*`'s form an island. (Two '`*`' are adjacent if they are horizontal, vertical or diagonal neighbours). Your task is to print the number of islands in the bitmap.

A single `*` also counts as an island.

Sample Input:

```
.........**
**......***
...........
...*.......
*........*.
*.........*
```

Sample Output:

```
5
```

Winner is entry with smallest number of bytes in the code.

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Aren't 5 stars in the top right corner considered as one island? Then your example has 4 islands.

Comment: the screen doesn't wrap. one island in each of the corners + the lone `*` island

Comment: But by your definition, an island is a group of '*' characters, implying more than one.

Comment: oh fair point. stand-alone `*`s are also islands.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Mathematica <strike>188 185 170 115 130 46</strike> 48 chars

**Explanation**

In earlier versions, I made a graph of positions having a chessboard distance of 1 from each other.  `GraphComponents` then revealed the number of islands, one per component.

The present version uses `MorphologicalComponents` to find and number clusters of ones in the array--regions where `1`'s are physically contiguous. Because graphing is unnecessary, this results in a huge economy of code.

---

**Code**

```
Max@MorphologicalComponents[#/.{"."->0,"*"->1}]&
```

---

### Example

```
Max@MorphologicalComponents[#/.{"."->0,"*"->1}]&[{{".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "*", "*"}, {"*", "*", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "*", "*", "*"}, {".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."}, {".", ".", ".", "*", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."}, {"*", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "*", "."}, {"*", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "*"}}]
```

5

---

**How it works**

Data are input as an array; in Mathematica, this is a list of lists.

In the input array, data are converted to `1`'s and `0`'s by the replacement

```
/.{"."->0,"*"->1}
```

where `/.` is an infix form of `ReplaceAll` followed by replacement rules. This essentially converts the array into a black and white image.  All we need to do is apply the function, `Image`.

```
Image[{{".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "*", "*"}, {"*", "*", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "*", "*", "*"}, {".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."}, {".", ".", ".", "*", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."}, {"*", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "*", "."}, {"*", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "*"}} /. {"." -> 0, "*" -> 1}]
```

[image: islands]

The white squares correspond to the cells having the value, 1.

The picture below shows a some steps the approach uses. The input matrix contains only `1`'s and `0`'s.   The output matrix labels each morphological cluster with a number.  (I wrapped both the input and output matrices in `MatrixForm` to highlight their two dimensional structure.)

`MorphologicalComponents` replaces `1`s with an integer corresponding to the cluster number of each cell.

[image: processing]

`Max` returns the largest cluster number.

---

**Displaying the Islands**

`Colorize` will color each island uniquely.

[image: colorize]

Comment: This isn't working as written on v7 because `MorphologicalComponents` wants an `Image`, but even on v9 shouldn't this be `Max@MorphologicalComponents[d/.{"."->0,"*"->1}]`?  That is, the replacement done first?  `Max` would disappear before the replacement was done, would it not?

Comment: I have V9, @Mr.Wizard is right. 46 characters is the right number.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  The replacement is carried out before the application of MorphologicalComponents.  Must be a precedence thing.

Comment: Hi @DavidCarraher, my point is not about "->" but that the expression `Max@MorphologicalComponents@d/.{"."->0,"*"->1}` do not work, what make sense is `Max@MorphologicalComponents[d /. {"." -> 0, "*" -> 1}]`, so you have one more character.

Answer (score 9):

### Ruby 1.9 (<del>134</del> <del>121</del> <del>113</del> 110)

Takes the map on stdin or the file name of the map as the first command-line argument, and prints the number of islands to stdout.  Using a basic recursive flood-fill.  Improvements welcome as always!

```ruby
c=0
gets$!
c+=1while(f=->i{9.times{|o|$_[i]=?.;f[o]if$_[o=i+(o/3-1)*(~/$/+1)+o%3-1]==?*&&o>0}if i})[~/\*/]
p c
```

Similar to David's colorize, you can also get it to display the different islands by changing `$_[i]=?.` to `$_[i]=c.to_s` and `p c` to `puts$_`, which would give you something like this:

```
.........00
11......000
...........
...2.......
3........4.
3.........4
```

(at least until you run out of digits!)

Some test cases:

```
.........**
**......***
...........
...*.......
*........*.
*.........*
```

5

```
......*..**....*
**...*..***....*
....*..........*
...*.*.........*
*........***....
*.....*...***...
*.....*...*....*
****..........**
*.........*.....
```

9

```
*
```

1

```
****
****
....
****
```

2

```
**********
*........*
*.******.*
*.*....*.*
*.*.**.*.*
*.*.**.*.*
*.*....*.*
*.******.*
*........*
**********
```

3

Comment: I like the last test. Thinking inside the box!

Answer (score 1):

### C, 169 chars

Reads map from stdin. Had no luck improving the recursive flood-fill function `r(j)` although it looks like it could be.

```
c,g,x,w;char m[9999];r(j){if(m[j]==42)m[j]=c,r(j+1),r(j+w-1),r(j+w),r(j+w+1),c+=j==g;}main(){while((m[x++]=g=getchar())+1)w=g<11*!w?x:w;for(;g++<x;)r(g);printf("%i",c);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <del>223</del> 203 Bytes

Thank you to [Step Hen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/65836/step-hen) and [Arnold Palmer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72137/arnold-palmer) for shaving off 20 characters of spaces and unnecessary parenthesis!

```python
s=input()
c=[(s.index(l),i)for l in s for i,v in enumerate(l)if'*'==v]
n=[set([d for d in c if-2<d[0]-v[0]<2and-2<d[1]-v[1]<2])for v in c]
f=lambda x,p=0:p if x&n[p]else f(x,p+1)
print len(set(map(f,n)))
```

I thought that using list comprehensions might decrease the number of bytes, but it didn't provide any significant improvement.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##VY3NbsMgEITvfoo9hZ8SK/YxCk@COFADKhLeIEMs9@ldcJRE3cNqv9HMTvotP3cc9z3LgOlRKOsmqWjuA1q30chEYP6@QISAkKGdQawNHD5mt5jiqil4womUq@5QquwKVfaw2macIPjzeLPqos9rXbfRoD2EoQlDFfTRcbyddOdlNPO3NbCJJC/XVPOwnVAl7WJ24GnVvwbWpSVggeiQtsrZJOoFMsb2XZH@NZwTQTh/QaP@M0/iH@Lv3D/qOdF/)

I keep trying to trim it around the n (neighbors) list, but I haven't been successful. Maybe someone else will have some ideas for that section.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Here's [217 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY1BjsMgDEX3OQWrYiiNmi6rchLEggTQIBEHBRplTp8J6XSq@QvL7/vbTt/la8LbtmUZMD0LsGaQCnIb0LoVIhOB@WkmkQQkmdQ2iKWCw@foZlPcHgqecirlohuUKrsCyh5RW4MDCZ6YPoNVV31Z9sIeN4P21@uq11VPH5@O44NuvIxm7K0hq0jyek/1Sj9NEdYTqqSZi9kRD/v03LEmzQELiQ4B6v/RJPAC2a5tU7R9i3MqKOdvqNR@9CL@If63949aTvUP "Python 2 – Try It Online") by removing some spaces. The Python parser is really lenient :P

Comment: You have more whitespace than needed. Remove the spaces between `(s.index(l),i)` and `for`, `enumerate(l)` and `if`, `-v[0])<2` and `and`, `p=0:` and `p`, and `bool(x&n[p])` and `else`. You also have more parenthesis than needed in your print statement, since you have 2 groups surrounding `set`. Edit: Beat by StepHen cause doing stuff on mobile isn't ideal.

Comment: [203 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY3NbsMgEITvfoo9hZ8SK/YxCk@COFADKhLeIEMs9@ldcJRE3cNqv9HMTvotP3cc9z3LgOlRKOsmqWjuA1q30chEYP6@QISAkKGdQawNHD5mt5jiqil4womUq@5QquwKVfaw2macIPjzeLPqos9rXbfRoD2EoQlDFfTRcbyddOdlNPO3NbCJJC/XVPOwnVAl7WJ24GnVvwbWpSVggeiQtsrZJOoFMsb2XZH@NZwTQTh/QaP@M0/iH@Lv3D/qOdF/) combining @StepHen's and my suggestions, plus changing the conditionals a bit.

Comment: Thank you both for the help! Python's leniency keeps surprising me : )

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 100 bytes

98 bytes of code + 2 bytes for `-p0` flags.

```perl
/.*/;$@="@+"-1;$~="(.?.?.{$@})?";(s/X$~\*/X$1X/s||s/\*$~X/X$1X/s)&&redo;s/\*/X/&&++$\&&redo}{$\|=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#TYrBDoMgGIPvPsXG/hAtkV/PhMhjcOA4b0tm5Cjy6kyzsa1Nmq9Nb9dlXh@XfhkKa7AhZ4VToh8NZStaPR3eyO3dJEwb2VMOOHL0HFOKHEDZf3on5Trfn@Zc2bOUSlF4b/tGIdmhFF0FNEBFNPqnk1EZ3/8fa7wA)

An adaptation (or rather a simplification) of my [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113778/55508) to the challenge [How Many Holes?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113764/how-many-holes). You can find explanations of how this code works on this other answer (it's a bit long to explain, so I prefer not to retype the entire explanations).

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 233 bytes

Too long, compared to other answers. Port of my answer to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113764/how-many-holes).
[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#nU9BboMwELz7FZaiymuzUFBvUB8QX8iByPIhIkS1FCzUJqrpoV@npklbUqGGctjR7MzOrrbPpbHt6QicVDImpTzUFnIVax4mZHPuBrqr97SANU8JddjJNaFmT3PVaeX0I4tYeuHS86zZtlDgm2nBK@IhUI2x4IIES35utw5cmGA8tKg6HPzO@xuOg9d9eZyT1ydzqJlgxtKXUwM5Ks1TI795ZOyuduAneFYFMskKAHMXvpdo7j36De2zsUda9Sul2IrhqDT@KPRKoZMzF0X3flPEkM4GMWo1UqpG8r/gM64mts6F4Z1f4VsXr29Ppm/9/HdaTIzPuh0tvS2W/r0EtP4A)

```
A=input()
c=0
X=len(A[0])-1
Y=len(A)-1
def C(T):
 x,y=T
 if A[y][x]<'.':A[y][x]='.';map(C,zip([x]*3+[min(x+1,X)]*3+[max(x-1,0)]*3,[y,min(y+1,Y),max(y-1,0)]*3))
while'*'in sum(A,[]):i=sum(A,[]).index('*');c+=1;C((i%-~X,i/-~X))
print c
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, 158 bytes

```
function f(s){w=s.search('\n');t=s.replace(RegExp('([*@])([^]{'+w+','+(w+2)+'})?(?!\\1)[*@]'),'@$2@');return t!=s?f(t):/\*/.test(s)?f(s.replace('*','@'))+1:0}
```

Noncompeting ES6 answer (language postdates challenge) for 132 bytes:

```
f=s=>s!=(s=s.replace(RegExp(`([*@])([^]{${w=s.search`
`},${w+2}})?(?!\\1)[*@]`),`@$2@`))?f(s):/\*/.test(s)?f(s.replace(`*`,`@`))+1:0
```

Port of my answer to [How Many Holes?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113764/how-many-holes) (yes I'm jumping on the bandwagon, now that I've seen two other people port their answers).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 225 bytes

```python
g=map(list,input())
q,w,t,r=len(g),len(g[0]),0,range
def l(i,j):
 if 0<=i<q and 0<=j<w and g[i][j]=='1':g[i][j]=0;l(i+1,j);l(i-1,j);l(i,j+1);l(i,j-1)
 return 1
print sum(l(i,j)if g[i][j]=='1'else 0 for j in r(w)for i in r(q))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3BjoMwDETv@QqLS2PVlew9dsmXIA5IDWwimkIIQvv1LIEiVVpf/Maj8Qy/6ecVvta1M89m0L2bErkwzEkjqpEWShRNb4PukPZVcY3EFJvQWfWwLfTakce7AtcCl8aVIzThkdGXy45d5erK18Zc5HI/BX9vwats0Qy3E8hf5Q03QQXRpjkGEDVEFxJM81MfhVvb51/bTxYY2lcEDy5A1Atm4Q4xIq5rVYgIs0hBxQGZ@JhM2@105b/Le7qo/wA)

Comment: [-1 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY7BioNADIbvPkXw0gnNQrLHrvMk4kHo6GawUx1HZJ/ejkqhsDkk35@Q/Bn/0u8zfG9bbx/taAadE2kYl2QQi4lWShTt4ILpkY5Sc4PEFNvQu@LuOhiMksdbAdoBV1arCdpw39FX64F9rU3tG2svcrm9Bf8cfmT0S0hJrzkjGU8@65yvkh@A6NISA0gxRg0J5uVhTr9s9nnWDbMDhu4ZwYMGiGbFXegpJsRtq0sRYRYpqTxhJz5jp9x7T@X/lI/tsnkB), suggested by an anonymous user